# Android Bluetooth pairing for audio device

Tags: android, bluetooth, xamarin.android

I need to send and read audio from a bluetooth headpiece. I have implemented a Broadcast receiver to detect when a device is paired. This works fine and detects the device when the app starts and the device is already paired to the phone. However if I start my app and the device is not paired, the broadcast receiver does not detect when the device subsequently pairs to the device. How can I set up the receiver to detect when a SCO device pairs to the phone after my app has started?
This is my broadcast receiver:

```
 public class BluetoothReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public AudioManager Audiomanager { get; set; }

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //https://www.programering.com/q/MDN5ATMwATk.html

        Android.Media.ScoAudioState state = (Android.Media.ScoAudioState)intent.GetIntExtra(AudioManager.ExtraScoAudioState, -1);

        if(state == ScoAudioState.Connected)
        {
            //record
        }
    }        
}
```

And this is how I am instantiating it (in a non UI thread):

```
        private void StartAudioBroadcastReceiver()
    {
        try
        {
            AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);


            m_bluetoothReceiver = new BluetoothReceiver()
            {
                Audiomanager = manager
            };

            manager.Mode = Mode.Normal;

            bool bluetoothMicAvailable = manager.IsBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall;


            if (bluetoothMicAvailable)
            {
                manager.BluetoothScoOn = true;

                RegisterReceiver(m_bluetoothReceiver, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ActionScoAudioStateUpdated));

                manager.StartBluetoothSco();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: do you try to register your broadcast as soon as the app opens and un register when the app is closed?

Comment: @FurqanKhan yes I do

Comment: In Android BOND_STATE_CHANGED action can be used for bonding events.